# looking for a function that doesn't do anything/ waits

Tags: c

for C, is there a function that takes an int and doesn't execute next statement ?

```
printf("a");
wait(500);
printf("b");
```

b will be printed after 500ms after a is printed out. something of the sort. sorry for the stupid question but i wasn't sure how to go about searching for such function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing like that in standard C.  However, POSIX defines the [`sleep()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) function (which takes an argument in seconds), [`usleep()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep) (which takes an argument in microseconds), and [`nanosleep()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/nanosleep) (nanosecond resolution).

It is also possible to use the [`select()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) function with `NULL` for all three file descriptor sets to sleep for sub-second periods, on older systems which don't have `usleep()` or `nanosleep()` (this is not so much a concern these days).

Comment: If you want Windows, it has the function "sleep()" which takes microseconds.

Comment: Grant Peters: milliseconds, I believe.

Comment: The Windows API has `Sleep()` (capital S), which takes milliseconds:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for the sleep() or usleep() functions.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows you could try:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    // Do nothing for 5 seconds...
    Sleep(5000);

    return 0;
}
```

Read more about this, [here (official doc)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298(VS.85).aspx) or [here (linux too)](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/30079).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) if you're on *nix.