# Adding "time interval" in a for cycle

Tags: c++

Supposing I have the following program (I will write only the essential!):

```
for (i = 1; i<=100; i++) 
{
    cout << " Hello World!\n "; 
}
```

Running that will produce 100 Hello World directly.  How can I make this where the loop will wait a certain duration like 1 second before it executes again?

Comment: C **or** C++? There is a difference!

Comment: This is for C++, but I would like to know also for C! :)

Comment: You will probably need to look up your OS API for time delay or sleep functions.

Comment: @cad: there is, and this is clearly C++. (Knowing what language it actually is could be useful to the OP as well.)

Comment: @Jongware I was rather referring to the general fact that C is distinct from C++.

Comment: Suggestions for C under a couple of different OSes: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2353685/2564301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
unsigned int microseconds = 1000 ;

for (int i = 1; i<=10; i++)
{

    cout << " Hello World!\n ";
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(microseconds));
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since C++14, you can use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) and the new user defined time intervals:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
for (i = 1; i<=100; i++) 
{
    cout << " Hello World!\n "; 
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15dafff0de6044f5)</kbd>

If you only have C++11 support it would be

```
for (i = 1; i<=100; i++) 
{
    cout << " Hello World!\n "; 
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}
```

This does require `<thread>` and `<chrono>`

Comment: Have I to include some library? Because it gives me error (precisely it says that the "s" in "1s" has not been declared)